# Installing ceph from tarball package

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ceph

I am new in ceph. I am trying to install particular version of ceph from source code on ubuntu 14.04. I follow ceph [documentation](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/install/build-ceph/). There're 2 installation mode there which is installing from ceph directory and create a tarball.

I've tried install from the build directory,I install ceph from the build directory by run `sudo make install` and ceph place on  `usr/local/bin`. but I got problem if i modify the code and recompile. if I have 3 VM, I've to recompile to all of those VM.

And now I am using a tarball of ceph. However, I did not find any guideline to install it from tarball source inside the documentation

what should I do after I get the tarball of ceph and how to install it?
advices are very appreciated.

Comment: If you want to use ceph instead of customizing it, you can use ceph-deploy to install it.

Comment: in the future, i plan to do some changes insides parts of ceph monitor. that's my reason to install it via tarball